# Connecting to SQL Server 2017 from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2017

Pretty much as the title says, has anyone tried connecting to SQL Server 2017 via Oracle SQL Developer?

I downloaded the latest jTDS (jtds-1.3.1-dist) but this only seems to support SQL Server 2012 (not too surprising as the latest jTDS was released in 2013).

There doesn't seem to have been a release since then, so when I try to connect to SQL Server I just get a 'Driver version not supported' message.

Comment: 1) There is no such thing as SQL Server 2018, so you may want to correct that in the question.  2) The jTDS driver will connect to later versions of SQL Server--we have applications using it connected to SQL Server 2017.  However, there is a bug in the latest jTDS release that causes TLS 1.2 to fail if you are using encrypted connections that require TLS 1.2, so you have to use an unreleased dev build to support TLS 1.2 3) Have you tried the Microsoft JDBC driver?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I just installed SQL Developer 19.2.1.247 and jTDS 1.3.1 and was able to connect to a SQL Server 2017 system with an unencrypted connection.

Comment: @TonyHinkle - SQLDeveloper does not support the Microsoft JDBC driver -- yet.  It is a known issue.  https://community.oracle.com/message/15389595#15389595